# Set button centerhorizontal after changed the position

Tags: android, button

I'm writing an application for android and I have difficulties with set a button CenterHorizontal after I changed the buttons position. I have created a button in an xml file and I changed it's position randomly.

Xml:

```
   <Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="90dp"
     android:layout_height="90dp"
     android:background="@drawable/pocs"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/level"
     android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

Java code:

```
        final Point sizePoint = new Point();
                    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(sizePoint);
                    int mScreenWidth = sizePoint.x;
                    int mScreenHeight = sizePoint.y;

                    btn.setEnabled(true);
                    Random r = new Random();

                    x2 = r.nextInt(mScreenWidth - 100);
                    y2 = r.nextInt(mScreenHeight - 100);

                    btn.setX(x2);
                    btn.setY(y2);
```

I do it 10 times, and after that I'd like to put the button in the middle of the screen like that :

```
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
         (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)btn.getLayoutParams();

    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    btn.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

And nothing happens, the button stays where it was at last time. But when I don't change the buttons position then it works correctly and the button jumps in the middle of the screen. Is it possible to do same after I changed the buttons position 10 times?

Answer (score 0):

LayoutParams are only used for initial positioning of the element.

SetX / SetY changes that position after layout has already been positioned.

Instead, you should either save the buttons position (GetX, GetY) or calculate the new position 
`setX((screenWidth - buttonWidth) / 2)` & `setY((screenHeight - buttonHeight) / 2)`

Comment: Yes I have tried this but the button is not exactly in the middle of the screen when I use this code. But if there is no other solution I will use this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using margins instead of `setX` and `setY`.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) btn.getLayoutParams();
params.leftMargin = 50; // Your X coordinate
params.topMargin = 60; // Your Y coordinate
btn.setLayoutParams(params);
```

And to align in center

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) btn.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, 0);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
btn.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

NOTE: Replace `params.leftMargin` and `params.topMargin` with random values.

Comment: Thank you for you answer but I've got an error message for this line: 
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START, 0);
And the error message:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=16; index=20

Comment: For which line exactly?

Comment: For this : 
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START, 0);

Comment: Could you please remove that line and check?

Comment: I have deleted that line and nothing happened again. Have you any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: Can you check by using `wrap_content` for `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`?

Comment: Unfortunately it's same for both situation.